# Get ID when insert data using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have some table look like this:

Person:

```
--------------------
|     Person       |
--------------------
| IDPerson         |
| IDName           |
| IDAndress        |
-------------------
```

Name:

```
--------------------
|     Name         |
--------------------
| IDName           |
| FirstName        |
| MiddleName       |
| LastName         |
-------------------
```

Andress:

```
--------------------
|     Andress      |
--------------------
| IDAndress        |
| Hamlet           |
| Ward             |
| District         |
| City             |
| Zipcode          |
-------------------
```

Account:

```
--------------------
|     Account      |
--------------------
| IDAccount        |
| IDPerson         |
| Username         |
| Password         |
| Level            |
-------------------
```

Now, if you want to add a new account, we need to create a new person. To create a new person, we need to create a new Name and Andress. Then add idName, IDAndress Person table, then add to the table IDPerson Account. How to get idName, IDAndress, IDPerson just created to add? Suppose if you get the largest ID in the table, the error can occur if more people register at the same time. Somebody can help me?

Comment: If u are using PHP use http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php to get the last inserted id which is for the current query..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mysqli::insert_id` if you are using PHP and MySQLi

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');

$sql = "INSERT INTO Person (name, address) VALUES ('test name', 'some address')";
$result = mysqli->query($sql);
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysqli->insert_id;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You should not post examples with `mysql_*` functions since they are deprecated and will not be supported for long.

Comment: Edited the deprecated functions.

Answer (score 1):

Mysqli_insert_id could serve the purpose. First run the insert query to insert values in the table `name` and store the Id of this table in a variable.

```
$nameid = mysqli_insert_id($link); // where $link is the handle for the db connection
```

Then run the insert query to insert values in the table `andress` and store the Id of this table in another variable.

```
$andressid = mysqli_insert_id($link); // where $link is the handle for the db connection
```

Finally you could use these variables where desired. This [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO address VALUES ('a','b','c','d','e') SELECT id
```

This is a query that will insert the entered values, but at the same time return the id. Since this is done using one query, there is no risk that another user adds his address just before you fetch the id.